# php variable scope - include/required scripts vs ajax

Tags: php

I would like to understand php variable persistence between included/required php scripts and php scripts called via ajax:

one.php:

```
<? 
include "two.php";
echo "from two: ".$myvar;
echo "<br>";
?>
<script> 
myfunction();
function myfunction(){
let url = "three.php";
$.ajax( url:url, success function(result))}
</script>
```

two.php:

```
<? 
$myvar = "hello";
?>
```

three.php:

```
<? 
echo "from three: ".$myvar;
?>
```

What I see is that when I run one.php I get:

from two: hello

from three:

It seems the variable, $myvar, is available when included in the scope of script one.php but when script three.php is called by script one.php the variable is not available to it. This seems somewhat inconsistent.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. When you include a script, it's essentially the same as duplicating its code there.

Comment: that's what i would've thought

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I get `from two: hello<br>from three: hello`

Comment: the code you posted can't be what you actually ran, since it needs to have quotes around the filenames. Post your real code.

Comment: yes, you're right, the 'real' code is more like the one updated with script three.php being called as an ajax function.

Comment: You are not "including" three.php into one.php with Ajax. You are simply requesting data from it through ajax. So in this case three.php is a standalone script. Hence it has no idea about `$myvar`

Comment: The AJAX request doesn't happen until after `one.php` finishes, it's a separate script invocation. If you want variables to persist, use session variables.

Answer (score 3):

Please add this line 
include "two.php"; 
In three.php file .